# value is not a member of (String, Float) - sparkshell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to execute following command in `spark-shell`

```
val products = sc.textFile("/public/retail_db/products")
val productsMap2 = products.
filter(product => product.split(",")(4) != “”).
map(product => (product, product.split(",")(4).toFloat))


productsMap2.sortBy(_._4, false).take(10).foreach(println)
```

Getting below error

> error: value _3 is not a member of (String, Float)

What is wrong in above statement?

Comment: what is the type of productsMap2?

Comment: What is `productsMap2`? What does the data look like? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`productsMap2` is `RDD[(String, Float)]` So while printing you can't access `_4` element as it doesn't exists. You can either sort by your `String` which is first element `_1` or `Float` which is second element `_2` of your `RDD`. Change your print statement to following

```
productsMap2.sortBy(_._2, false).take(10).foreach(println)
```